# Properly extending a JS class with corresponding @types folder

Tags: typescript, class, types

I am building a TS project where I want to extend a class from an existing JS package. Said JS package has a corresponding @types package, and because of it, everything resolves nicely inside the project. However, when I build and export the package, the information about the class I'm extending does not appear to come along.

I basically do like this:

```
import { SomeClass as JSClass } from "JSPackage";

class SomeClass extends JSClass {
  constructor() { super(); }
  aNewFunction(str: string) { ... }
  override anOldFunction(int: number) { ... }
}

export default SomeClass;
```

Then I build the project with tsc.

When I attempt to use the new SomeClass in other projects, TS only sees `aNewFunction()` and `anOldFunction()`. Any preexisting fields of the extended class are not inferred. How may I export the extended class with all the fields defined both by me and the `JSPackage`? I'm guessing I must explicitly include the type from the @types package. If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a simple mistake on my part. I had not added the @types package as a project dependency, only as a dev dependency. Adding the @types package as a dependency fixed the problem.